# Log4j Issue with Spring Web

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I am getting following WARN while deploying Spring RESTful webservice in my project:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Log4j is properly configured in my project but I don't know why

Comment: What is your log4j configuration file looks like?

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue by setting up log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by setting up log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout